# What OpenGL version is available in a QT app on MacOS Desktop platform?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, glsl

The highest version of GLSL I was able to use in a QT app on MacOS Desktop is 120. Is it possible to use a higher version?

If I try GLSL 130, for example:

```
#version 130
...
```

I get error 'version 130 is not supported'.

**EDIT1:**

My QT version is 5.14.2

Comment: qt version is...?

Comment: From what I recall OpenGL 4.5 should be available but MacOS only supports core profiles.  Try `#version 450 core` .

Comment: Actually, from [this table](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202823) it appears 4.1 is the latest commonly supported version.

Comment: @RichardBarber QT version is 5.14.2